# Advantages of Synchronization over Locks API

Tags: java, multithreading

Every blog or Explanation I see advantages of Locks API over Synchronization.

I want to know are there any advantages of Synchronization over locks, or any scenario where I should prefer Synchronization and not Locks.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean the synchronized statement and methods keyword? The main advantages of implicit locking is that requires less code and unlocks automatically when leaving its scope. For simple lock/wait operations it's the perfect solution.

So the following code

```
public void myMethod() {
    synchronized(this) {
       // concurrent stuff
    }
}
```

is perfectly equivalent to

```
final private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void myMethod() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        // concurrent stuff
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

and

```
synchronized public void myMethod() {
    // concurrent stuff
}
```

You can also use different objects for synchronization (they are not affected in any way, being only control points):

```
final static private Object sync = new Object();

public void method1() {
    synchronized(sync) {
        // concurrent code involving static members
    }
}

public void method2() {
     synchronized(this) {
         // concurrent code affecting this instance
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @Shepard's answer, using `synchronized` is less error prone.  Consider these mistakes which can lead to locks not being released:

```
final private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void myMethod() {
    lock.lock();
    // concurrent stuff
}

public void myMethod2() {
    lock.lock();
    // concurrent stuff that might throw an unchecked exception
    lock.unlock();
}

public void myMethod3() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
       // concurrent stuff
       lock.unlock();
    } catch ( ... ) {
       ...
    } finally {
       ...
    }
}
```

The first one is liable to show up in testing, but the latter two may not.

You can't make any of these mistakes with `synchronized`.

---

However, `Lock` is useful despite these considerations:

- Locks allow you to implement different locking strategies such as non-reentrant locking and multi-reader / single-writer locking.
- Locks allow you to hold locks across scope / block structure boundaries.  (This makes your code harder to reason about, but it is necessary for some use-cases; e.g. event-based designs where locks need to be held across multiple event handlers.)
- The Lock API allows you to test a lock, acquire a lock without blocking, or with a timeout, and define `Condition` objects.